# How to get lines starting with some word from file and if no match get lines starting with another word

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

What is the best way to get lines from a file starting with a certain string and if no such lines are found, then get lines starting with another string.

For example. There are two strings

```
    aaa
    bbb
```

and there is a file with strings. Need to get all the lines starting with `aaa`. If there are no such lines, then get all lines starting with `bbb`.

For file with lines

```
    aaa 1
    bbb 2
    aaa 3
    ccc 4
```

return must be

```
    aaa 1 
    aaa 3
```

For file with lines

```
    zzz 1
    bbb 2
    zzz 3
```

return must be

`bbb 2`

I know how this can be done but my solutions seem to me too clumsy.
I tried, for example, this:

```
            List<String> lines = null;
            List<String> result = null;
            Integer maxValue = null;
            try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("test.txt"))) {
                lines = stream
                .filter(l -> l.startsWith("aaa") || l.startsWith("bbb"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
            } catch (IOException e) {}
            if (lines != null) {
                result = lines.stream().filter(l -> l.startsWith("aaa")).collect(Collectors.toList());
            }
            if (result == null) {
                result = lines.stream().filter(l -> l.startsWith("bbb")).collect(Collectors.toList());
            }
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: typically you would post what you have tried, and say what is going wrong.  otherwise this is a 'do it for me' post...  at least describe your algorithm that is too clumsy

Comment: Ok, sorry. I added example what Ive tried in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could group your lines by their substring and call the method getOrDefault on the generated map. Assuming that your file contains at least one line beginning with aaa or bbb something like below:

```
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("test.txt"))) {
    Map<String,List<String>> map =  stream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s->s.substring(0, 3)));
    map.getOrDefault("aaa", map.get("bbb")).forEach(System.out::println);            
} 
catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hardcoding "aaa" and "bbb" you could try using a loop. Maybe try something along these lines?

```html
List<String> lines = null;
List<String> result = null;
Integer maxValue = null;
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("test.txt"))) {
 lines = stream
 .filter(l -> l.startsWith("aaa") || l.startsWith("bbb"))
 .collect(Collectors.toList());
} catch (IOException e) {}
if (lines != null) {
 for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
  char letter = (char) ('a' + i);
  result = lines.stream().filter(l -> l.startsWith("" + letter + letter + letter)).collect(Collectors.toList());
  if (result != null) {
   break;
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to print matching line then you can refactor your's code with below

```
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("text.txt"))) {
           stream.filter(l -> l.startsWith("aaa") || l.startsWith("bbb"))
           .forEach(line -> System.out.println(line));
} catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
}
```